# Vue3 - Set HTML Attribute as a prop in subcomponent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I pass the prop type over to the HTML attribute "type" found in the input tag?

When running this code in the browser, the password input is still working like a standard text input.

```
    <div class="mt-4 place-items-center grid gap-4 grid-cols-1 auto-rows-max">
        <Card>
          <form>
            <Input label="Username" type="text"/>
            <Input label="Password" type="password"/>
          </form>
        </Card>
    </div>
```

Input.vue

```
<script lang="ts">

    export default {
        props: {
            label: String,
            type: String,
        },
    }

</script>

<template>
    <div class="mb-2">
        <label class="block text-stone-50 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for={{label}}>
            {{label}}
        </label>
        <input class="border-2 border-stone-700 rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-stone-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id={{label}} type={{type}}/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to bind type, try like `:type="type"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using to bind the html attributes to your props is wrong: the double curly brackets `{{ }}` can be used only to add text inside the content of a tag. Instead you should bind reactive values to HTML properties in the following way: `<tag :propertyName="propertyVariable"></tag>`. In your case, for example:

```html
    <template>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label class="block text-stone-50 text-sm font-bold mb-2" :for="label">
                {{label}}
            </label>
            <input class="border-2 border-stone-700 rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-stone-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" :id="label" :type="type"/>
        </div>
    </template>
```

You can find a complete explanation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#attribute-bindings).